# QT : Exited with saying " During startup program exited with code 127"

Tags: qt, qt4

I Had a Qt program which was working fine in Linux . We migrated our linux from 32bit to 64 bit and while trying to run the same program again throws me a error given below

`"During Startup program exited with code 127"`

In the Output window I also see the following:

> &"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Invalid
>   argument\n" &"Cannor exec /bin/tcsh: No such file or directory.\n"

does anyone have any idea on this error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Thread in QtCentre has the same problem solved.

Look at [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26506-amp-quot-warning-GDB-Failed-to-set-controlling-terminal-Invalid-argument%5Cn-quot)

Hope that helps...